# Change domain of joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, multiple-domains, domain-mapping

i installed a "Joomla" on a domain. now i want to change the domain of my "joomla". how can do it? what changes must do in "joomla" to view correctly my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Joomla" automatically change and fix with new domain. there is no need to change anything in "Joomla".